# URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs) in build.gradle

Tags: android, xml, maven, xsd

I am working on a `android` app using android studio.  When Analyze -> Inspect Code, I got the error as the post title and an error

> "Cannot resolve symbol
>   'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd'".

Is this error critical or it can be ignored(because I can run the simulator without a problem)? How to fix it? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click on the code with issue, click on the red bulb symbol, then select the 'Fetch external resource'. This solves the problem.